# Finding facebook page handle / id from a string in python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way by which we can search for existing facebook page from a company's name?
We can do similar search for twitter which gives us the handler name. I am searching for a way in python where in the user can type any company's name such as "PNC Bank" and the program checks the existence of a facebook page related to the string entered and output its facebook page id ("pncbank" in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Search API, you can search for Pages by name: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search